# How to execute a function at the time of its definition in Scala

Tags: scala

Is there a more idiomatic way to execute a function upon its definition in Scala? Can I do better than the following `Function1` definition with its immediate execution?

```
scala> (new Function1[Int, Int] { def apply(v1: Int) = v1 }) (5)
res0: Int = 5
```

Are there use cases that justify such calls? I have none, but got curious after I'd been asked about it and thought it might be helpful to find out.

Comment: `scala> ((x:Int) => x * 2)(3)
res0: Int = 6` How does this look? Seriously, why do you want that? :)

Comment: `{(_: Int) + 1}(5)` `res0: Int = 6`. Just because you can doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scala does have a terse syntax for anonymous functions (which you can call immediately):

```
((x: Int, y: Int) => x + y)(4, 5)
```

The only use case I am aware of for such instant calls is from another language - JavaScript - where they are heavily used for scoping. But in Scala, you can just define scopes with curly brackets, like:

```
{
    val a = 5
}
{
    val b = 4
    // a not accessible here
}
```

so I don't see a use case where such a construct would be useful in Scala.

Comment: Conceivably, you could use it to one-line test your functions in REPL, before you pass them to something else.

Comment: @som-snytt read the answer before you rant - I do anwser this question to the best of my knowledge. If you can prove my assumption wrong, write an answer yourself. Otherwise...

Comment: I've found the pattern useful when refactoring out functions from a block. I can keep the code in place and easily get an overview of which variables are being accessed in the outer scope and that I will need to pass to the new function.